# How to detect the value changes of a cell linked to a spin button of form controls as a change event?

Tags: excel, vba

How to detect the value changes of a cell linked to a spin button of form controls as a change event? I tried but change event detects only when the cell value is changed by keyboard inputs.
Is there any indirect way to detect the spin button value change as worksheet(cell) change event?
Please help me with tips...

Jean

Comment: The spin button itself has a change event. Hook to that instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works and is very simple. I couldn't think of it